# Adding background color to table rows

Tags: forms

I was wondering if it is possible to change the background color of a table row.

I want to display certificate files, and if that certificate is going to expire in longer than 30 days the color green would be good. If it is less then 30 days color orange and if it's expired color red.

I tried finding it on the internet but I can't find anything like this.

This is how my current column data looks like.

```
'c3' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@uploaded', array('@uploaded' => date('d-m-Y', $val->upload_date)))),
    ),
```

I already tried adding '#class' => array('bgcolor' => '#ffffff'), or just 'bgcolor' but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Complete code

```
$qry = db_select('push_notifications_api', 'n');
$qry->join('push_notifications_certificates', 'u', 'n.ios = u.cert_id');
$cert_table = $qry
->fields('n', array('app_name', 'ios'))
->fields('u', array('cert_id', 'cert_name', 'upload_date', 'expiration_date'))
->OrderBy('u.expiration_date', 'ASC')
->execute();

$form['certificates']['table'] = array(
 '#theme' => 'table',
 '#header' => array(t('Application'), t('Certificate'), t('Uploaded'), t('Expiry Date')),
 'rows' => array(),
 '#weight' => 30,
);

foreach($cert_table as $key => $val) {

$form['certificates']['table']["#rows"]["'r$key'"] = array(
    'c1' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@app_name', array('@app_name' => $val->app_name))),
    ),
    'c2' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@cert', array('@cert' => $val->cert_name))),
    ),
    'c3' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@uploaded', array('@uploaded' => date('d-m-Y', $val->upload_date)))),
    ),
    'c4' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@expiry', array('@expiry' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($val->expiration_date))))),
    ),
);
}
```

Comment: As side note, you are missing a _#_ in `'rows' => array()`.

Comment: The table is working correct but I'll check it. Thanks!

Comment: It works because in the loop you use `$form['certificates']['table']["#rows"]`. It is only a detail, not something that explains why the code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class for the row and add background for this class via the css

```
$row = array(
  array(
    'data' => array(
      array( 'data' => 'cell1'),
      array( 'data' => 'cell2'),
      array( 'data' => 'cell3' ),
    ),
    'class' => array('my-class'),
  )
);

print theme('table', array('rows' => $row));
```

Comment: Okay. And how to add a class to 1 complete row instead of 1 column?

Comment: I updated my answer. Try it.

Comment: Unfortunately that also doesn't work. I edited my post with the complete code of the $form['table']. Already thanks for helping!

Comment: I updated my answer and checked it. It works for me.